# SendAsync Payload too large .NET 6 Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis, google-cloud-run

I have 2 .NET 6 applications. A UI and a Web API. Locally in development the UI makes an HTTP Client request that sends an excel file to Web API and get error. Payload Too Large (413). I fixed it by adding the 2nd line of code in Program.cs of the Web API project only.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args); 
builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(options => options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = long.MaxValue);
```

And it works. But when its deployed to Google Cloud Run Container (Container is Windows Based Running on IIS), it does not work. It does not work means I still get "Response code 413".

**Since its IIS based on my container I have tried many things, such as below to no avail.**

```
builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;
});

<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <!-- 1 GB -->
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're running on a windows container?

Comment: @davidfowl - Hey, we have another team that handles that and do not know the reason for going with it. From my debugging locally on development, Kestrel works so I should ask him if we can test in Google CloudRun with a Linux container then.

Comment: Or use Kestrel in a windows container?

Comment: @davidfowl Will try Kestrel in Windows container first